# Python subprocess.popen over network

Tags: python, network-programming, subprocess

Python subprocess.popen is easy as pie on local machine, but is it possible to call it over a network?

Example, say I have 3 PCs, one is called workstation-pc, the others are called node1-pc and node2-pc...

Is it possible to call a process on, say, node1-pc, from workstation-pc, preferably without having to run special server software on node1-pc?

In any case, many thanks for any response!

Gilles

**EDIT**
Forgot to mention that I am using Python 3

Comment: no you would need to create a message passing system between the 3 networked machines ... something like celery maybe ...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the use of either:

- [execnet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/execnet)
- [fabric](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fabric)

**Example with Fabric:**

```
from fabric.api import env, run

env.hosts = ['host1', 'host2']

def mytask():
    run('ls /var/www')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I forgot to mentiuon that I am using Python 3, and Fabric does not work with it!

Answer (score 0):

Fabric is probably the way to go, however, there is nothing to stop you executing remote commands via `ssh` in *nix environments.

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', 'node1-pc', 'ls', '-ltr', '/etc'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
```

`out` will contain the stdout of the remote process.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I use Python 3, so no Fabric for me!
I tried the Popen call, but get an error, no matter what I try "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: Windows is different. You need to use a suitable ssh client and server.